# I am trying to update a field in mongodb and it is automatically becoming an array when updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, e-commerce, categories

I have a `category` collection and `product` collection. `Product` collection has `category` field which saves category name from `category` collection. Whenever I update the product, the `category` field of the product becoming an array which has previous values of `category` and updated value

```js
    updateProduct:(productId,productDetails)=>{
        return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
            db.get().collection(collectionNames.PRODUCT_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id:objectId(productId)},{
                $set:{
                    name:productDetails.name,
                    price:productDetails.price,
                    description:productDetails.description,
                    category:productDetails.category
                }
            }).then((response)=>{
                resolve()
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us an example document before and after the update? And sample `productDetails` being passed to the function? Even better would be a mongoplayground.net demonstrating the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
db.get().collection(collectionNames.PRODUCT_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id:objectId(productId)},{
  name:productDetails.name,
  price:productDetails.price,
  description:productDetails.description,
  category:productDetails.category
})
```

I'm pretty sure that `$set` is for arrays

Comment: `$set` is definitely not just for arrays, documentation can be found [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/).